# Closed form version of partition and combination problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, integer-partitions

We have an original set of n integers, $0, ... , (n-1)$. From these integers generate a set of $k$-tuples, with repetition where order does not matter. From this, want to know the probability that any two tuples will have the same sum.

I have attempted to go about this using partitions and working backwards.
The range of possible sums goes from $0$ to $nk$. The brute force method I thought of was to go through each sum, generate each possible partition (limited by $k$ pieces of $n$ size), and count how many partitions are possible with these bounds for each sum. I have various equations, but I run into a few issues. Namely, with partitions, I have found recursive equations for counting $p(n,k)$, where the size of of the partitions is bounded, but I cannot find a closed-form version of this that includes a bound on the size of the pieces. I have found Ferrer's graphs and a way to bound pieces that way, but I am not sure how to put this all together.

(I have also done this analytically in py3, generating the list of combinations-with-replacement, determining all of their sums, and from there counting exactly how many all share the same sum. I can't post the image because I don't have enough rep, but it actually resulted in a normal curve.)

I have no idea if the way I am going about this is correct. I am a computer science student, and I am seeking a closed-form solution for the probability of two tuples having the same sum based on $n$ and $k$. Thanks!

Comment: "of $n$ integers" do you mean specifically the integers $1, \ldots, n$?

Comment: @JBL thanks for the clarifying question-basically, yes

Comment: Ok.  Here is some possible helpful information: the usual recurrence for the number $p(M, k, n)$ of integer partitions of $M$ into $k$ or fewer parts, each of which is at most $n$ is $p(M, k, n) = p(M, k, n - 1) + p(M -n, k - 1, n)$ (consider cases about the largest part).  The generating function $\sum_M p(M, k, n) q^M$ for the numbers $p(M, k, n)$ is the $q$-binomial coefficient $\binom{n + k}{k}_q$.

Comment: @JBL ok thanks, that is super helpful. I haven't taken a combinatorics class so I don't have these theorems on hand. 
However, once I have determined the count of partitions for each possible sum, is it then just a "colored marbles in a bag" type of probability question?

Comment: Be cautious! In real life the order does matter, so the probability computed by your method will be wrong.